# How to do something like Google/Wiki/Facebook search field?

Tags: html, input, autocomplete, autosuggest

Their search fields can type and have some kind of list is showing here.... For example, when I type "Wikipedia" , when I start type "W", it have "Wi", "Wii", "Will" , somethings like that... ...How to do something similar like this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Several javascript libraries provide this functionality. For example with jQuery, you can use the [Autocomplete pulgin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete). The link also includes a demo.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you are planning on using the auto complete there is a jquery plugin that can help with this feature.

Essentially you are capturing the data as a user types and are checking against an array of some type to see similar matches.  Your array can be statically set or be dynamic using ajax to query a script which returns data that is similar.

See:
http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin

Answer (score 0):

the jQuery liveSearch plugin will do this. Here is the plugin site with pretty detailed instructions for connection to a php search page: http://andreaslagerkvist.com/jquery/live-search/